# Print 3 chars of arrays values every time differently

Tags: php

Its hard to explain this in the title

I have array of different value. lets say this is the array:

```
$char = array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0");
```

how do I print every possible 3 char of this array.
like start off...

aaa

aab

aac

and so on...

Comment: Show us your effort please

Comment: @b001 I skipped math classes, now I regret this, I know that from 0-9, with 3 digits is 999 possibility, 36 char to gather how many possibility? I think i need to multiply 36 by 100. that result in 3600 possibility. so I for from 0 to 3600, and for each first chart will stay at 0 second 0 and third is going from 1 to 36 then second char with change from 0 to 1 and 3rd char with start counting again. I kind have long way to do it, but I need the possibility badly.

Comment: @KunalAwasthi I need to know what is the possibility of 36 char together is it 3600? I really don't know. I know how to loop.

Comment: @AbdullahSalma 46656 number of possible combinations according to me by searching on google.. try to search the problem over google or on your fav search engine.

Comment: A little clue:  Permutations without repetition: 42840. Permutation allowing repetition: 46656

Comment: @Stuart yes exactly what I needed. "Permutations".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the example of possible two alphanumerics

```
<?php
$start = base_convert("10",36,10);
$end = base_convert("zz",36,10);
for($start;$start <= $end;$start++){
  echo base_convert($start,10,36)."\n";
}
?>
```

[Live Demo](https://eval.in/961016)

You can start from `100` to `zzz` to get all possible digits of three  albhanumeric.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop 3's to find your desire output.

```
$char = array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0");
$length = count($char);
for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
    for($j = 0; $j < $length; $j++)
        for($k = 0; $k < $length; $k++)
            echo $char[$i].$char[$j].$char[$k]."<br/>";
```

Output:

```
aaa
aab
aac
aad
aae
aaf
aag
aah
aai
...
```